# htaccess 301 redirect a page with query strings to homepage

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have a domain that was previously owned before which was advertising products. I would like to 301 redirect all these back to the homepage if possible using .htaccess file.

Each product was built on this type of url:

```
/product.php?p=128842744
```

There's 100's of these query strings showing up so simply listing these 301 redirects would take a while.. like so

```
Redirect 301 /product.php?p=128842744 http://example.com
```

isn't there some sort of rewrite/redirect combination rule for me to do this to cover all query strings for product.php?

Only the part after "p=" changes for each url/string.

My website doesn't use query strings. I know basic knowledge of .htaccess file usage but it's a little confusing when coming to rewrite modules etc.

Any help to solve this would be great. Thanks

Comment: If you don't mention the `?p=1234` part it won't work ? just do a general rule like `/product.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^product.php$ /? [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I can confirm it works. 

I managed to get it to work this way too.. not sure if it's the correct way to do so, so I've stuck with your version.


RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^product.php http://www.domain.co.uk/? [L,R=301]

Comment: You can also do: `RewriteRule ^product.php http://steelbuildings.co.uk/? [L,R=301]`